# Can't Grab Query String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-services

We were provided function getQueryStringVariableByItemID for our project and are using function getData to use a web service for a game's details from a games table. We believe the getData part is working fine since we use a similar POST on another page. Is getQueryStringVariableByItemID not properly grabbing the query string?

We call getData with the body tag of html as onload="getData()". Many thanks in advance!

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getQueryStringVariableByItemID(ItemID) {
            //use this function by passing it the name of the variable in the query
            //string your are looking for.  For example, if I had the query string
            //"...?id=1" then I could pass the name "id" to this procedure to retrieve
            //the value of the id variable from the querystring, in this case "1".
            ItemID = ItemID.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]" + ItemID + "=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
            var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
            if (results == null)
                return "";
            else
                return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        function getData() {
            var ItemID = getQueryStringVariableByItemID(ItemID)

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./WebServiceTry.asmx/GetGameDetails",
                data: "{'ItemID': '" + escape(ItemID) + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var data = response.d;
                    $('#output').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        var Title = item.Title
                        var Price = "$" + item.Price
                        var Year = "Year: " + item.Year
                        var Developer = "Developer: " + item.Developer
                        var Platform = "Platform: " + item.Platform
                        $('#output').append('<li>' + Title + '</li>');
                        $('#output').append('<li>' + Price + '</li>');
                        $('#output').append('<li>' + Year + '</li>');
                        $('#output').append('<li>' + Developer + '</li>');
                        $('#output').append('<li>' + Platform + '</li>');
                        $('#output').listview('refresh');
                    });
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    $('#output').text(msg);
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ItemID you are passing in the getData(while calling inside the getData) should be undefined because the function doesnt have that variable.Pass a valid id and it will work fine

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am fairly new to javascript. What should I do to the getData code then?

Comment: Can you tell me the order of the method call??ItemId which is being passed in the getQueryStringVariableByItemID inside getData() should be undefined,because this variable is not even used anywhere.

Comment: Our method call order is the Getdata() function and then the getQueryStringVariableByItemID function. We've declared ItemID on a separate page within our project, and were attempting to use the getQueryString function to pass that value from our search page to this page to display the details of the selected result

Comment: okie...i think this ItemId is not accessible within this function.Are you sure ItemId is not undefined here??to access something which u have defined in another page(assuming its in another file/or in another class) u need to access this variable through a object unless u declare it in the window variable.